# Getting "not data-defined" label properties

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, labeling, c++

My plugin needs to read out the labeling of a feature layer. I can read via **QgsPalLayerSettings** the data-defined properties.

```
QgsDataDefined * dd = set->dataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings::Size);
if (dd!=nullptr)
{
    if (dd->isActive())
    {
        if (dd->useExpression())
        {
            QString sExpr=set->dataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings::Size)->expressionString(); }
        }
    }
```

But in most cases the user sets directly a value an then there is no dd! Surely it is very simple but I didn't find out.

How can I get label properties if they are not data-defined?

EDIT:

In between I found the member label (**QgsLabel**) of  **QgsFeatureLayer**, but the properties there are empty/standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I'm so blind. I can get the several labeling properties directly from the **QgsPalLayerSettings**. It has members like **textFont**, **textColor** ... But I have to look for the datadefined properties, even if they are active, the 'normal' properties are filled so the datadefined properties overwrite the others.